# How to format a number as percentage with 2 decimal places in Presto?

Tags: format, decimal, percentage, presto, trino

I have a number want to format it as percentage in Presto. I want to format 0.18932 as 18.93%.

I tried:

```
format('%s%%', decimal_number*100)
format('%s%%', round((a.decimal_number*100), 2))
```

Here is the result:
none formatted: 0.019435618
first method: 1.9435618000%
2nd method: 1.9400000000%

Any easier way to format it as 1.94%

Answer (score 7):

The [`format`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#format) function accepts any of the Java [format string specifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

```
presto> select format('%.2f%%', 0.18932 * 100);
 _col0
--------
 18.93%
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the same result but with a more complicated way. format('%s%%', format('%,.2f',0.18932 * 100))

Comment: Seems like "format" function is not available in "my" presto. There has to be another way

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who, like me, came here looking to round a `decimal` or `double` field down to `n` decimal places but didn't care about the `%` sign, you have a few other options than Martin's answer.

If you want the output to be type `double` then [`truncate(x,n)`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/math.html) will do this. However, it requires `x` to be type `decimal`.

```
select truncate( cast( 1.23456789 as decimal(10,2)) , 2); -> 1.23 <DOUBLE>
```

If you feel that the truncate is kind of useless here since the `decimal(10,2)` is really doing the work, then you're not alone. An arguably equivalent transformation would be.

```
select cast( cast( 1.23456789 as decimal(10,2)) as double); -> 1.23 <DOUBLE>
```

Is this syntactically better or more performant than `truncate()`, I have no idea, I guess you get to choose.

And if you don't give a hoot about what type results from the transformation, then I suppose the below is the most direct method.

`cast( 1.23456789 as decimal(10,2);`

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this using `format()` and `round()` combined:

```
select format('%s%%',round(count(*) * 100.00 / sum(count(*)) over(), 2)) as percent
```