# Casting Decimal to Currency in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a field `value(decimal(23, 2))` and I am querying over it like this:

`sum(value)` and as output i get `1200000.32`

I am trying to cast it to currency to get `$1.200.000,32` like this:

```
cast(sum(value) as money) == FAIL
sum(value::money) == FAIL
cast(sum(gmv::numeric) as money) == FAIL
```

How can I get the desired currency type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is no money type](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html) in presto. And Amazon's version of presto does not support [`format`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62763796/2501279) and I could not find any buld in function to format numbers. So you will need to either create and use some [user defined function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-udf.html) to do this, or use some replacing and regular expressions magic:

```sql
WITH dataset(d) AS (
   VALUES 
  (decimal '1'),
  (decimal '999.99'),
  (decimal '1000.1'),
  (decimal '101000.1'),
  (decimal '1000000'),
  (decimal '10001100.10')
 ) 
 
SELECT '$' || regexp_replace(replace(cast(d as VARCHAR), '.', ','), '(\d)(?=(\d{3})+,)', '$1.')
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| $1,00 |
| $999,99 |
| $1.000,10 |
| $101.000,10 |
| $1.000.000,00 |
| $10.001.100,10 |

Comment: Thanks @Guru Stron

Comment: @pouchewar was glad to help!